# MultiLocation type polkadot js

Tags: polkadot-js, typescript, types

I am trying to figure out correct way how to type MultiLocation type

I thought that I would do

```
import {MultiLocation} from "@polkadot/types/interfaces"
const location: MultiLocation = {
  parents: 0,
  interior: {
    x1: { generalKey: "0x0001" }
  }
};
```

but this does not work cause parents is **u8** and number does not work there etc
So I tried this solution which works

```
const loc: MultiLocation = api.createType(
  "MultiLocation",
  JSON.parse(
    JSON.stringify({
      parents: "0",
      interior: {
        x1: { generalKey: "0x0001" }
      }
    })
  )
);
```

but I do not like this solution. IS there a correct way how to type this ?
Thanks

Comment: How are you getting the type MultiLocation?

Comment: I updated my question.

Comment: I wrote some more comprehensive notes for constructing types here https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10705/how-can-you-use-polkadot-js-api-to-create-an-xcm-reserve-transfer-assets-xcm-v

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So you are very close to the correct answer. Using createType will automically set the type reference to the interface you assign. So the correct code here in typescript would be:

```typescript
const loc = api.createType(
    "MultiLocation",
    {
        parents: "0",
        interior: {
            x1: { generalKey: "0x0001" }
        }
    }
);
```

Then if you want the JSON value back:

```typescript
console.log(loc.toJSON());
```

Comment: Thank you Tarik for your help.