How to transfer assets from parachain to relay chain
As I'm new to substrate and polkadot I don't know how to transfer assets from parachain to relay chain using xcm can anyone please help me to do this.

Does this answer your question? How can I transfer assets using XCM?

I believe this question can be answered with this: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/10705/how-can-you-use-polkadot-js-api-to-create-an-xcm-reserve-transfer-assets-xcm-v

We built a library to abstract a lot of the difficulties for users to build extrinsics for sending xcm across any type of chain.
The lib is called asset-transfer-api. Here is an example of how an extrinsic would be built from a parachain to a relay chain.
The docs can be very helpful as well.
Here is an example of constructing, signing and sending an extrinsic using asset-transfer-api as well.
